# selecting an array corresponding to the value of an integer in while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have six arrays. with names arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4,arr5,arr6. I want to get the the array according to the value of an integer. I am incrementing the value of an integer in a while loop and there is an if condition in while loop. When if condition gets true, i want to get the array corresponding to the value of integer. i.e, if the value of integer is 5, i should get arr5! I don't want to do this in more if loops! I'm doing this in javascript!

So how can this be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object of arrays

```
var arrays = {
    0:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    2:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    3:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    4:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

or 
Array of arrays

```
var arrays = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]
```

suppose `index` is the integer to retrieve the array, then `arrays[index]` will give you a particular array.

Comment: Yes, i already got this idea and working on it! thanks for your answer!